# I get the following error when I try to use plt.contourf in python. "ufunc 'isfinite' not supported '" is there any way to fix it or plot another way?

Tags: python

the y_train,X_train, y_test, X_test all have been set up and the data is clean. I have couple of categorical columns as well as multiple float columns in my dataset.
the orginal X data is as below

[image]

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.fit_transform(X_test)
  
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA(n_components = 2)
X_train = pca.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = pca.transform(X_test)
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
```

**LogisticRegression(random_state=0)**

```py
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1,
                     stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1,
                     stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(),
             X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape), alpha = 0.75,
             cmap = ListedColormap(('yellow', 'white', 'aquamarine')))
```

[image]

I face the above problem when I try to run plt.contourf.

Comment: Would please copy-paste your error message instead of putting a screenshot?